# Impossibility of recovering the key of a keyed pseudorandom permutation

Tags: pseudo-random-permutation, adversarial-model, key-recovery

I'm currently working on some cryptography homework, but I'm stuck on this particular question.

> Let $F$ be a pseudorandom permutation with identical key length and
> block length (both equal to the security parameter $n$).
> Prove that there is no probabilistic polynomial time algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ that, on input
> $1^n$, and based on $n$ queries to $F_k(\cdot)$ (with
> $k \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^n$), recovers $k$ with probability $1$.

My initial idea was to prove this by considering the statement that for any family $F$, there must be some pair of keys $k, k'$ such that $F_k(x) = F_{k'}(x)$ for all $n$ queries $x$, and at some point using the bijectivity of pseudorandom permutations, but so far I've not managed to arrive at a proof. Does it make sense to prove this statement in that way, or is there something else I should think about? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask yourself if a PRP that allows you to extract the key could be secure.

Comment: @Maeher Of course not, but I'm worried that might be a circular argument...

Comment: Not at all. Assume that an algorithm exists that can extract the key as described. How can you use that algorithm to distinguish the PRP from a random permutation?

Comment: @Maeher If I'm not mistaken, PRPs we simply need to make $n+1$ queries an oracle; the first $n$ to find the key $k$, and the last one to have another value. We can then say that if $O$ is an oracle for $F_k$, then $O(x_{n + 1}) = F_k(x_{n+1})$ with probability 1, whereas if $O$ is uniformly random, then $O(x_{n+1}) = F_k(x_{n+1})$ with probability $2^{-n}$ allowing us to distinguish with non negligible probability $1 - 2^{-n}$. Does that sound correct/sufficient?

Comment: @Maeher Thinking about this some more, I realise I didn't treat the case when the $n$ queries to $O$ yield a combination of outputs which is not found amongst the $2^n$ possible $F_k$'s. I'm assuming there is some way to prove that this will not happen (perhaps combining the number of queries with the fact that $F$ must be a PRP and not simply a PRF), but I've not been able to find one yet.

Comment: You're on a good path to a solution. (There won't be an answer here, as site policy is not to answer homework questions.) That you will end up with $n$ queries that are inconsistent with *all* keys is indeed possible. In fact, it's likely. If the algorithm gives you a key, can you check that it's consistent?

Comment: @Maeher Yes, this can be checked in polynomial time by checking each of the $n$ query results is consistent with the output of $F_k$. If we find it to be inconsistent, then we can distinguish with certainty, whereas when the keys are consistent, we can simply proceed as I outlined in my previous comments. As far as I can see the only thing left to do is then to include this dichotomy in the computation of the probability of success in the distinguishing experiment. Is my assessment correct? If yes, is there a simple way to bound the probability of inconsistencies occurring?